# How do I set the size of elements in a user control according to property settings on the user control?

Tags: c#, silverlight

To make this simple:  I have a user control that consists of 2 rectangles.  At design time the user of the control sets the width of the user control and a default value for one of the rectangles which is a property of the user control.  I want to treat the default value as a percentage and set the width of one of the rectangles to that percentage of the other rectangles width.  The kind of difficulty I'm having is that I cannot get the width of the outer rectangle to set the other rectangles width as a percentage of (because everything seems to be 0 or NaN).  Here's some code:

User Control:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    <Rectangle x:Name="OuterRectangle" Fill="Red"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="InnerRectangle" Fill="Blue"/>

</Grid>
```

User Control code behind:

```
public partial class ucRectangles : UserControl
{
    public Double Percent { get; set; }

    public ucRectangles()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InnerRectangle.Width = Percent / 100 * OuterRectangle.ActualWidth;
    }
}
```

Main Page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <local:ucRectangles Width="400" Height="40" Percent="50"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you get the Grid to do all this for you that is what its good at:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Rectangle x:Name="OuterRectangle" Fill="Red" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
     <Rectangle x:Name="InnerRectangle" Fill="Blue" />
</Grid>
```

Now just fiddle with the star values of the column definitions, here is my implementation of the `Percent` dependency property:-

```
    #region public double Percent
    public double Percent
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PercentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PercentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PercentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Percent",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ShowCase1),
            new PropertyMetadata(50.0, OnPercentPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnPercentPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowCase1 source = d as ShowCase1;
        double percent = (double)e.NewValue;

        source.LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(percent, GridUnitType.Star);
        source.LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width = new GridLength(100 - percent, GridUnitType.Star);            
    }
   #endregion public double Percent
```

Note its the last two lines where the magic happens.

Answer (score 0):

ActualWidth would only be relevant after the Measure pass has taken place. You're trying to do it in the C-tor, which would be WAY before the Measure is happening.

Try and use the Event LayoutUpdated, which is bound to happen after the layout process finished.

Comment: Ok, this works, but I only need it to run once at start up, not every time the browser is resized or (whatever else) do I detach the handler within the handler itself.  Is this good practice?  Are there any implications?

Comment: That's quite legitimate, and there are no implications. just remove the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Handle (user control's) LayoutRoot's loaded event and move code inside it.

User Control XAML

```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Loaded="LayoutRoot_Loaded">
```

User Control Code Behind

```
 private void LayoutRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InnerRectangle.Width = Percent / 100 * OuterRectangle.ActualWidth;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: OuterRectangle.ActualWidth still comes in at zero

Comment: No it doesn't.. see the image above.. are you sure you handling event correctly and have code inside that event?

Comment: I've checked my code carefully to make sure it is the same as your's and I am still getting zero.

Comment: You are right, your code works, but the context is wpf rather than Silverlight so I suspect this is somehow the difference

Comment: Ohh.. I don't know how I missed the Silverlight Tag :s

Answer (score 0):

I know this seems answered already, but here's something similar I did last year for creating simple bar charts.  Just bind your percentage to the "Content" property and you'll get a auto-resizing bar without all the extra code...

```
<ContentPresenter Content="0.3" Height="30">   <!-- Bind the "Content" to your percentage -->
        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="YellowGreen">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Purple" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="{Binding}"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="{Binding}"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter>
```